# Assign a new column in a data frame containing sorted groups

Tags: r

A data frame with the rows containing some grouped data that are sorted is presented. It is needed to introduce a new column that has values depending on the values of some column.

If the first value is zero, then all the values for a group get the first non-zero value or `NA`, if there is no such value. Otherwise, if the first value is non-zero, then a fixed value is assigned, e.g. `-1`.

Example input data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
 name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
 value = c(0, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0 , 7, 0))
```

Example output data frame with the **calc** column created:

```
df <- data.frame(
 name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
 value = c(0, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0 , 7, 0),
 calc = c(6, 6, 6, 6, NA, NA, -1, -1))
```

Thank you in advance.

P.S.: Base R is preferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with base R:

```
df$calc <- unlist(tapply(df$value, df$name, function(x) rep(if(x[1]==0) x[x!=0][1] else -1, length(x))))
```

... and a better way:

```
df$calc <- ave(df$value, df$name, FUN = function(x) if(x[1]==0) x[x!=0][1] else -1)
```

It is better understandable in two parts:

First, write a function that corresponds to your desired conditions.

```
 doit <- function(x) if(x[1]==0) x[x!=0][1] else -1
```

Second, use it in `ave`:

```
 ave(df$value, df$name, FUN=doit)
```

|edit|

> How should the function be modified, if I want to assign to "calc" column a value from another column, e.g. "value2", corresponding to a first non-zero "value"?

Here, `ave` won't help you any more, you'll need to `split` the data frame and rejoin it.

```
df$value2 <- 101:108
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$name), function(x) {
  x $ calc <- with(x, ifelse(value[1]==0, value[value!=0][1], value2[value2!=0][1]))
  x
}))
```

Notice the second row in `function(x)` ... this is for *returning* the whole `x` instead of just the `$calc` component. The logical order is: split --> lapply --> do.call but it appears the other way round because of how the parentheses work. One could rewrite this using pipes from magrittr so that the logical order is preserved (a pipe `LHS %>% RHS` forwards the LHS as a first argument to the RHS, so a trick is needed with `do.call` where we want it to be the second argument.).

```
library(magrittr)
split(df, df$name) %>%
  lapply(function(x) {
    x $ calc <- with(x, ifelse(value[1]==0, value[value!=0][1], value2[value2!=0][1]))
    x
  }) %>% {do.call(rbind, .)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Here is one question though... In a case where "value" starts with zero: How should the funtion be modified, if I want to assign to "calc" column a value from another column, e.g. "value2", corresponding to a first non-zero "value"?

Comment: this will be slightly more complicated, in base R, i think you'll need first to `split` the data frame by groups, then do the calculations, and then rejoin it by `do.call(rbind, ...)` (see the edit above, I added this to my answer for better readability)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, calc := if(!value[1]) value[value != 0][1] else -1, name]
df
#   name value calc
#1:    A     0    6
#2:    A     0    6
#3:    A     6    6
#4:    A     3    6
#5:    B     0   NA
#6:    B     0   NA
#7:    C     7   -1
#8:    C     0   -1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by` and `case_when` with `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(calc = case_when(
    first(value) != 0 ~ -1., 
    max(value) == 0 ~ NA_real_,
    TRUE ~ value[value != 0][1]))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
  name  value  calc
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        0.    6.
2 A        0.    6.
3 A        6.    6.
4 A        3.    6.
5 B        0.   NA 
6 B        0.   NA 
7 C        7.   -1.
8 C        0.   -1.
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @andrew_reece's answer.
You can even skip `line max(value) == 0 ~ NA_real_`,as `calc` will be set to NA anyway, so ìfelse may be shorter to write:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(calc = ifelse(first(value) == 0, value[value != 0][1], -1))
```